# dynamic image name in ANGULAR4

Tags: html, angular

In assets folder, I already have images, but name will come from backend

name like `foo`

we have variable in component, say `public imageName` and foo will bind to this varialbe dynamically.

So in html i want to display this image 
I tried below code

```
<img [src]="/assets/{{imageName}}'.jpg'" class="img-thumbnail" alt="{{imageName}}" width="304" height="236">
```

but i m unabel to see the image, i am getting some html errors

Comment: The problem is that you are adding `'` between `.jpg`. Try removing those.

Comment: try this `<img src="/assets/{{imageName}}.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="{{imageName}}" width="304" height="236">`

Comment: thanks.. this works

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
<img [src]="'assets/'+imageName+'.jpg'" class="img-thumbnail" alt="{{imageName}}" width="304" height="236">
```

Comment: or `<img src="assets/{{imageName}}.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="{{imageName}}" width="304" height="236">`