# Change img [src] dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

I have component which have list of records

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    public wonders: WonderModel[] = [];

    constructor(private ms: ModelService){
        ms.wonderService.getWonders();
        this.wonders = ms.wonderService.wonderList;
    }

    ngOnInit(){}
}
```

this.wonders returns array of values like this 
[image: array of this.wonders]

I am trying to get that id value to image source dynamically like this

```
<div class="img-content" *ngFor="let wonder of wonders">
    <header class="img-content-header">
        <div style="width: 45px; display: table-cell;"> <img [src]='assets/images/{{wonder.id}}.jpg'  height="40px" width="40px"> </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">
            <div>{{wonder.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

While doing so I am getting this error

> Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected
>   at column 14 in [assets/images/{{wonder.id}}.jpg]

Can anyone suggest any possible solution for that.

Comment: Weren't you able to find anything here on SO ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203279/parser-error-got-interpolation-where-expression-was-expected)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46407334/5468463

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to bind like this

```
<img src='{{ "assets/images/" + wonder.id + ".jpg" }}'
```

`[]` is not compatible with `{{ }}`.

Comment: I have something like that but when the wonder.id changes it takes some time  to the browser show the results.

Comment: In my case i have to use relative path, seems like  it does not work. 
ie. <img src='{{ "../../assets/images/" + var + ".jpg" }}'>

Answer (score 30):

You can do it like :

```
[src]='"assets/images/"+wonder.id+".jpg"'
```

**OR**

```
src='assets/images/{{wonder.id}}.jpg'
```

Answer (score 16):

You are using interpolation and property binding in the section

```
[src]='assets/images/{{wonder.id}}.jpg'
```

You could either remove the property binding

```
src='assets/images/{{wonder.id}}.jpg'
```

or remove the interpolation

```
[src]='assets/images/' + wonder.id + '.jpg'
```

For more information check out [Property Binding or Interpolation in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation)

Answer (score 5):

its interpolation , so you dont need `[]` that is needed when you create full path from the back-end typescript and assign it , so just removing `[]` will work for you

```
<img src='assets/images/{{wonder.id}}.jpg'  height="40px" width="40px">
```

---

`[]` is helpful when you are binding full vaule which so coming from typescript, example

```
<img [src]='path'  height="40px" width="40px">
```

in type script you are having path variable

```
 const path = 'imagepath.jpg';
```