# Attach SVG that was created in code (not fetched from server) to an element in angular (avoid getting 'unsafe')

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, svg.js

In my angular 10 app, I am using a library (svg.js) to create an svg in the client (although I think my question is independent from what library I am using).

```
    let svg = SVG().size(this.widthpx, this.heightpx).svg(); //returns an svg, 
    //although I treat it as any in typescript because I do not know any better
```

Once that svg is created I would like to display it. Ideally as the background image of a div, but I can live with setting it as src of an `<img>`.

How do I do this?
I tried using the way described here:[Angular dynamic background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575368/angular-dynamic-background-images?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
<div [style.background]="svg"></div>
```

I also tried the following ways, as suggested here: [Change img [src] dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671139/change-img-src-dynamically)

```
<img id='other' [src]="svg">
<img id='other' src={{svg}}>
```

As I am new to both typescript and angular, my guess is, there is a logical error here on my part. I probably just cannot set some svg-like-variable as background/src, but need to process it somehow? Give it an URI? Cast it to some particular type?

I am aware, the svgjs library has a attachTo() method on their object. As this happens outside of angular and does not let me do everything I want to down the road, I would like to take things into my own hands.

I can also describe a little more what is not working. Using `src={{svg}} or [src]="svg"` *almost* works as far as I can tell. But src is "unsafe".

```
<img _ngcontent-dgo-c96="" id="other" src="unsafe:<svg xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&quot;(...shortended...) </svg>">
```

Using the [style.background] approach creates an empty svg element and at the wrong position.

Comment: svg.js is a dom library. Using it will always result in unsafe code because angular generates dom via vdom and svg.js changes what was generated by angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to do that you need to

1. define an Angular-reference in the said div (eg. `#svgContainer`)
2. address that reference via `ViewChild`
3. change the `backgroundImage`

I have provided a working solution here (see `app.component.ts` and `app.component.html`:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-buck-r13ck?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you very much! Two comments: 1. Would you happen to have an example setting it as src of an image, too? In the https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef documentation angular encourages use of other types of databinding. Is there a more angularly way of doing it? Or am I interpreting too much into the documentation?

Comment: You're welcome. 
1. i have updated the codesandbox to reflect your request: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-buck-r13ck?file=/src/app/app.component.ts
2. if you want to dynamically change the style of a rendered dom element you have to use ElementRef. In this case you cannot avoid it.